# Writing custom filters for Play! 2.2 in Java

Tags: java, playframework

I have a simple scenario: automatically add a response header to every HTTP response; and I want to do this in Java.

Looking at `src/play-filters-helpers/src/main/java/play/filters/*`, there are examples of [Actions](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaActionsComposition) which can be applied as annotations. I'd like to avoid adding `@AddMyHeader` to every handler.

Looking at the [Scala Filters](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaHttpFilters) in `src/play-filters-helpers/src/main/scala/play/filters/*` and `GzipFilter` specifically, I see a clear mechanism, but I'm not familiar enough with Scala to extrapolate to Java.

So: where do I go from here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a good way to create and use Filters from Java yet.  But you can do what you need pretty easily with Scala.

Create a new file `app/filters/AddResponseHeader.scala` containing:

```
package filters

import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object AddResponseHeader extends Filter {
  def apply(f: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])(rh: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    val result = f(rh)
    result.map(_.withHeaders("FOO" -> "bar"))
  }
}
```

And create a new file `app/Global.scala` containing:

```
import filters.AddResponseHeader
import play.api.mvc.WithFilters

object Global extends WithFilters(AddResponseHeader)
```

That should apply a new response header to every response.

**UPDATE**: There is a way to use this in a `Global.java` file:

```
@Override
public <T extends EssentialFilter> Class<T>[] filters() {
    return new Class[] {AddResponseHeader.class};
}
```

And also change the `object AddResponseHeader` above to `class AddResponseHeader`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, although I had to remove my Global.java, which ended up looking like: `object Global extends WithFilters(AddResponseHeader, new GzipFilter())`

Comment: Is there any chance it can be added to `Global.java`?

Comment: Posted a way to do that in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a nice Java API available for creating Play Filters. However, you can adapt the existing Scala APIs into a nice Java template.

For example:

```
import play.api.mvc.*;
import scala.Function1;
import scala.concurrent.Future;
import scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1;

public abstract class JavaFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public Future<Result> apply(Function1<RequestHeader, Future<Result>> nextFilter, RequestHeader requestHeader) {
    return nextFilter
            .apply(requestHeader)
            .map(new AbstractFunction1<Result, Result>() {
                     @Override
                     public Result apply(Result currentResult) {
                         return Apply(currentResult, requestHeader);
                     }
                 },
                    play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.defaultContext());
}

@Override
public EssentialAction apply(EssentialAction next) {
    return Filter$class.apply(this, next);
}

public abstract Result Apply(Result currentResult, RequestHeader requestHeader);
}
```

Example implementation:

```
import play.api.mvc.RequestHeader;
import play.api.mvc.Result;

public class HelloFilter extends JavaFilter {

@Override
public Result Apply(Result currentResult, RequestHeader requestHeader) {
    if (requestHeader.headers().get("X-Filter").isDefined()) {
        ResultAdapter resultAdapter = new ResultAdapter(currentResult);
        return resultAdapter.WithHeader("X-Hello", "World!");
    }
    return currentResult;
  }
}
```

For a further explanation of how this works, see my blog post about it [here](http://www.ivanmartinvalle.com/blog/10271105/play-framework-java-filters)

Answer (score 4):

To add a custom filter (MyFilter.class) create a Global.java file in the root package. Tested in PlayFramework 2.3.x and Java (JDK8)

```
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public <T extends EssentialFilter> Class<T>[] filters() {
        return new Class[]{MyFilter.class};
    }
}
```