# Enable CORS on Angular + Scala Play

Tags: angularjs, scala, google-chrome, firefox, playframework-2.0

Using AngularJS 1.2.16 and Scala Play 2.2.0, I'm trying to enable CORS.

Here's my request on the front-end. Basically it's a `POST` that sends a JSON with `userName` and `password` fields.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/login
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/app.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 ...
Request Payloadview source
  {userName:foo, password:bar}
```

And here's the back-end `checkPreFlight` method for allowing the headers of my `POST` request.

```
  def checkPreFlight = Action {
    Ok("...").withHeaders(
      ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN -> "*",
      ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS -> "POST",
      ACCESS_CONTROL_MAX_AGE -> "300",
      ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS -> "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,
                                         Referer, User-Agent")
  }
```

`routes`:

```
POST    /login                      controllers.Home.login
OPTIONS /login                      controllers.Home.checkPreFlight
```

My Chrome Browser's console shows:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore 
not allowed access.
```

Note that the initial `OPTIONS` request returned a 200, however the `POST` was cancelled in the Network tab. Chrome (per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21103081/409976)) may be disabling CORS requests for security purposes?

When I tried on Firefox, both the `OPTIONS` and `POST` succeeded with a `200` status for each. However, Firefox still showed an error in the console:

```
200 OK 12ms 

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote 
resource at http://localhost:9000/login. This can be fixed by moving the resource 
to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

Additionally, my promise (which called the POST to `/login`) gets rejected, i.e. I added a `console.log` to the success and failure cases.

Comment: Can't speak for server-side, but I'm pretty sure nothing needs to be done on the angular front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've shown that Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set in the response to the OPTIONS pre-flight request. But (at the time I wrote this) you haven't shown the header being set in the response to the POST request itself. As it's an easy mistake to make, I'd hazard a guess that's where your error is.

The header needs to be present in both responses. That means, for the code you've given, that you need to set the header in both `controllers.Home.checkPreflight` and `controllers.Home.login`

Comment: I guess that is not necessary to add headers on each endpoint of the app, hire ants for doing that (and pay then well) or Instaed use a filter or something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144788/enable-cors-in-java-play-framework-2-2-x