# same request is calculated twice in onRouteRequest for play framework 2

Tags: java, playframework

I use play framework 2.2.1.

I want to calculate the number of total requests received by playframework. However, I've found that every request is added up by multiple times e.g. 2,3 etc. when i handle it in the onRouteRequest method as below.

Any idea what is the problem?

```
@Override
public Handler onRouteRequest(play.mvc.Http.RequestHeader request){
    TotalRequests +=1;
    return super.onRouteRequest(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the method should be invoked twice. However, rather than using this method, you could alternative make use of a [filter](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaHttpFilters). Filters are not yet available in the Java API but it should be relatively easy to write a Filter that does exactly what you are looking for, see for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307850/writing-custom-filters-for-play-2-2-in-java).

Another alternative, rather than rolling your own request counting, would be to make use of a plugin such as the [play2-metrics](https://github.com/sdb/play2-metrics) plugin that integrates the [metrics library](http://metrics.codahale.com/).