# Play Framework CORS Headers

Tags: scala, playframework, cors

I'm trying to set CORS Headers for my play framework app. Specifically I'm getting this error

```
cannot load http://127.0.0.1:9000/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I figured I could easily handle this by following these instructions:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter

However, after doing this. nothing has changed.

```
curl -I localhost:9000/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 4540
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2016 20:03:33 GMT
```

My conf is:

```
play.http.filters = "global.Filters"

play.filters.cors {
  allowedOrigins = ["http://www.example.com", "*"]
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept"]
}
```

and my Filters.scala file is:

```
package global

import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.http.DefaultHttpFilters
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter

class Filters @Inject() (corsFilter: CORSFilter)
  extends DefaultHttpFilters(corsFilter)
```

If someone could tell me why the filters don't seem to be getting applied to the responses, that'd be great.

Answer (score 16):

Play filters are enticing, but when they do not work as expected, as you noticed, the magic is not that easy to track down.

I prefer to use something like this:

```
implicit class RichResult (result: Result) {
  def enableCors =  result.withHeaders(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*"
    , "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" -> "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD"   // OPTIONS for pre-flight
    , "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> "Accept, Content-Type, Origin, X-Json, X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With" //, "X-My-NonStd-Option"
    , "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" -> "true"
  )
}
```

Then you can easily invoke it in your response like this:

```
Ok(Json.obj("ok" -> "1")).enableCors
```

It's easy to understand, can be placed only where you want to enable CORS, and very easy to debug!

Answer (score 6):

I would not recommend writing/using any code to enable CORS which is basically a framework feature and only needs configuration.

The stuff you copied from the documentation is correct:

- `cors.conf` where you modify the `play.filters.cors` settings. But you seem to have misconfigured something, e.g. the `allowedOrigin = *` should be configured as `null` in the config. (Have a look at the [documentation page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter) and the linked [reference.conf](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/resources/confs/filters-helpers/reference.conf))

`# The allowed origins. If null, all origins are allowed.
play.filters.cors.allowedOrigins = null`

- You have correctly enabled the `CORSFilter` in your `Filters.scala`
- Now test your configuration with a correct cURL CORS request:

`curl -H "Origin: http://example.com" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" \
  -X OPTIONS --verbose \
  http://localhost:9000/`

Comment: what if i do not provide config option?will it pick by default values?

Comment: If you do not configure anything, e.g. don't enable the `CorsFilter` enabled then there will be no CORS for you webapp (all preflight requests will eventually fail since there is no mapping for `OPTIONS` requests)

Comment: `filters {
    disabled += play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
    enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"

    // Website
    hosts.allowed = ["."]
  } `this much configuration enough to enable cors?  and thats fine even if i do not write below option config?                                                            `play.filters.cors {
  # allow all paths
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
 # allow all origins (You can specify if you want)
 allowedOrigins = null
 allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
 # allow all headers
 allowedHttpHeaders = null
}`

Answer (score 4):

for me it worked after one day (maybe cash or other things)

application.conf:

```
play.http.filters = "filters.Filters"

play.filters.cors {
  # allow all paths
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
 # allow all origins (You can specify if you want)
 allowedOrigins = null
 allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
 # allow all headers
 allowedHttpHeaders = null
}
```

build.sbt :

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
filters,
....
)
```

in package filters.Filter :

```
package filters;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import play.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;
import play.http.DefaultHttpFilters;

public class Filters extends DefaultHttpFilters {

CORSFilter corsFilter;

@Inject
public Filters(CORSFilter corsFilter) {
    super(corsFilter);
    this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
   }

public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
    return new EssentialFilter[] { corsFilter.asJava() };
}
}
```

and in my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    method:'GET',
    url: xxxxxxxx',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {'url': yyyyy,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
    },
    success: function(data) { 
....});
```

i have no more error, in prod and in local environment !! thank you all