# CORS error while sending request from Browser to play server even after sending CORS header

Tags: angularjs, playframework, cors

I have a REST API developed using Play Framework/Java and front end developed in Angular JS.

I am trying to call a POST method fron the Angular Client to the server using the following code:

```
$scope.login = function () {
console.log('login called');
var loginURL = 'http://localhost:9000/login';
var loginInfo = {
    'email': $scope.email,
    'password': $scope.password
};

$http({
    url: loginURL,
    method: 'POST',
    data: loginInfo,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log('SUCCESS: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    $scope.greeting = response.status;
}, function (response) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
});
}
```

This is the code at my server:

```
public Result doLogin() {
    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    result.put("status", "success");
    return ok(result).withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
}
```

And this is the application conf file:

```
#allow all hosts.
play.filter.hosts {
    allowed = ["."]
}

#allow CORS requests.
play.filters.cors {
  allowedOrigins = ["*"]
}
```

Yet even after enabling CORS, I am getting error in console in both Firefox and Google Chrome:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9000/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
>       ERROR: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:9000/login","data":{"email":"xxx","password":"xxx"},"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}

I do know that the server is sending the correct response and the correct header because when I do the POST from Postman, I can see the response and also the headers containing {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"} in Postman.

So then, what could be the problem? Is there something I am missing from the Client side?

Answer (score -1):

The difference between POSTMAN request and browser request is browser sends an OPTIONS request before the actual POST / GET request.

To be able to accept OPTION request with your play framework  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST" ,"OPTIONS"]
for follow this link 
[Play Framework 2.3 - CORS Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152277/play-framework-2-3-cors-headers)

This causes a problem accessing CORS request from a framework (like angularjs). It becomes difficult or the framework to find what was the options request for and take action properly.

For fixing your problem you will need to analyze how the options request going and how it's being interpreted and how to overcome. But in general, I suggest using "fetch" built-in request for this, which supports the promises so can be chained easily with angularjs code

so your code will look something like this

```
    $scope.login = function () {
  console.log('login called');
  var loginURL = 'http://localhost:9000/login';
  var loginInfo = {
      'email': $scope.email,
      'password': $scope.password
  };
fetch(loginURL, {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
  },
  body: loginInfo
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log('SUCCESS: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
  $scope.greeting = response.status;
}, function (response) {
  console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this way, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Do you see the option request before the post request in the Network Tab? what is the response for that both in case of the $http request and the fetch request?

Comment: Actually in the network tab I only see the OPTIONS request and nothing else in both cases (fetch and http) the only difference is that in case of fetch, the cause is 'fetch' and in case of http, the cause is 'xhr'. both have a status of 404.

Comment: If you are getting 404 status , that means you have not included a Options request handler at all on the server side . You have to add a options request handler on the server side too . you have not included that part in the snippet .   You can google how to add options request in a playframwork