# How do you set up a redirect from www to non-www with Play! Java 2.3 running the default server?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I recently set up a website and pushed it to production using Digital Ocean. However, I noticed that for both SEO purposes and to make Facebook Share work appropriately, I should set up my server to redirect www. requests to non-www. I'm running Play! Java 2.3 with a PostgreSQL database and the default Netty server. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways of redirecting. I wouldn't say DNS-redirects are the correct and only way of doing it, it's one way. Google is just fine with you doing a 301 redirect with Play.

Here's one way of accomplishing it with Play! filters (scala):

```
object NonWwwFilter extends Filter {

  def apply(f:RequestHeader => Future[Result])(rh: RequestHeader): Future[Result] =
    if (rh.host.startsWith("www.")) {
      Future.successful(Results.MovedPermanently("https://" + rh.host.substring(4) + rh.uri))
    } else {
      f(rh)
    }
}
```

Comment: Andreas, do you know a way to do it in Play Java?

Comment: Got it working! For anyone else who might want to know how to do it, you need to change object to class and follow this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307850/writing-custom-filters-for-play-2-2-in-java

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is to do in not on the framework/webserver side, but on the DNS-server side.

You can do it in DNS-management area of GoDaddy or any other domain name registrar.

Comment: A DNS server can't do this. It's an HTTP redirect, so it has to be done by a web server. Your domain registrar can only do it if they're doing HTTP forwarding for you, which isn't usually the case.